# Entity Framework 4 - lifespan/scope of context in a winform application

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

Sorry for yet another question about EF4 context lifespan, but I've been wondering about this for a while and I do not seem to find the answer. I'm not very familiar with lots of patterns or overcomplicated stuff (in my point of view) so I want to keep it simple.

I work with an ASP.NET application where the context is managed by each http request which is a very good approach in my opinion.

However I'm now working with a winforms application and I sometimes have transactions or reports that will not perform very well if I simply create the context for each query. Not that this performance issue is a very problematic thing, I just want to hear if there's a simple strategy as per HTTP request in ASP.NET for winforms?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't create a context for each query. At the same time, don't create a context that gets used for the entire lifetime of a Form (or your application).

**Create a context for a single Unit of Work** (which can encompass many queries).

That way you have all of your changes encapsulated in the context and you let Entity Framework wrap the database calls in a pretty little transaction without having to worry about it yourself.

I prefer to abstract the Repository and Unit of Work patterns out of the Entity Context so that I can use them independently (which makes everything very clear). MSDN actually has a decent article on the details:

[MSDN - Using Repository and Unit of Work patterns with Entity Framework 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)

Comment: & @dotnedify - Thanks for this, I'm looking at doing this exact same thing for our wretched DataSet driven forms. Upvotes for all.

Comment: I got the idea. My problem is I was creating static classes with static methods to handle methods such as Insert/Update/Get and the result is having to pass context for every function  instead of creating an instance of a Manager class and passing it to the class level. Thanks it really opened my eyes!

Comment: @Tom - glad i indirectly helped, for once!

Comment: i am not good with the terminologies in programing,  do you mean its good to use using(contxt = new contxtDBEntities()){somthing to do with}