# EntityConnection Memory leak in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, memory-leaks

I have a .NET application that uses Entity Framework as its ORM. After running the application for a few hours, the application becomes unresponsive when the garbage collector runs and eventually starts to log "Out of Memory" errors.

I took a dump of the application and it mentions that that the EntityClient Objects are taking 95% of the memory.

[image: Image from Dot Net profiler]

On digging deep into references I see :

[image]

Can someone help me with why these `EntityConnection` objects are living forever? From the application point of view, we are not even creating these objects in the code. The framework might be creating these.

Sorry, but I am a .NET novice :( Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Grab one of those instances and see what is holding it (repeat until you trace it back to your code). In all likelyhood, you're not disposing of some object(s).

Comment: As usual: what's the life cycle of the the EF context(s)? When do you instantiate them and when are they disposed?

Comment: Hi @xxbbcc : I have added another screenshot with the fields. I also have a question why should I essentially dispose these objects off ? Shouldn't they be garbage collected themselves ?

Comment: How are you using the DbContext of the entity framework, do you properly dispose them after use? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666824/entity-framework-and-context-dispose

Comment: Sorry but why do I need to dispose these off ? Shouldn't they automatically be Garbage collected ?

Comment: @Geek If the GC cannot tell that you're done with something, those objects will stay around until you shut down your process.

Comment: I agree @xxbbcc . I understand GC well (Java background :-) ). Novice to EntityFramework and .Net. If you can please do post a link to something where there is a description of dispose(). I think dispose() is like finalize() in Java which is called before the Object is Garbage collected.

Comment: @Geek Read about `IDisposable` and look up EF tutorials that show how to use the DB context. When something implements `IDisposable`, you're supposed to clean it up when you don't need it anymore because it tells you it's using unmanaged resources.

Comment: Thanks Dude @xxbbcc. I am beginning to understand.

Comment: @xxbbcc : Jesus the damn thing looks like it is the Model of MVC and is being used to store configuration tables. I can't dispose that off :-(

Comment: @Geek Without seeing your code it's impossible to tell what's wrong but likely something needs changing. You shouldn't have any DB code in your MVC layer - it should all be separated off to a business layer / repository. The MVC layer shouldn't need to know anything about a database.

Comment: We need you to show us what happens inside your context class. It looks like some static/singleton event handler is tied to connection events. And please refer to my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold I am still searching. Can you give me an idea as to how EntityConnection and DBContext are related. This might be a obvious answer for some but I am still figuring out. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I can't start elaborating on broad issues how several moving parts are interacting without knowing what you need *specifically*. Why don't you follow up on repeated suggestions to show your code?

Comment: @GertArnold : Ya it is too broad. Let me see if I can put some snippets around. The code is too widespread and you might have guessed that I am not too well versed with it. I am probably asking very basic questions. Thanks for your time.