# Implementing IDisposable for Entity Framework in custom class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, idisposable

I use Entity Framework like

```
public sealed class CacheManagementHelper 
{
   private readonly GJobEntities db = new GJobEntities();

   public List<User> GetUsers()
   { 
       return db.Users.ToList();
   }
}
```

And MS Visual Studio 2019 suggests following

> Warning   CA1001  Implement IDisposable on 'CacheManagementHelper'
>   because it creates members of the following IDisposable types:
>   'GJobEntities'. If 'CacheManagementHelper' has previously shipped,
>   adding new members that implement IDisposable to this type is
>   considered a breaking change to existing consumers.

I found some clue here

[Entity Framework and calling context.dispose()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666824/entity-framework-and-calling-context-dispose)

But it is still unclear if I have implement `IDisposable`.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You are not disposing the disposable type `GJobEntities` right?

Comment: @swdon Yes you are right

Comment: The lifetime of an `IDisposable` must be explicit, when you use it inside your code. How are you using this `CacheManagementHelper` class? It is created as needed? It is created as a singleton? Either way, you have to decide how to bound your `DbContext` to your class: create it inside your method, and wrap it inside a `using` statement, or keep your code as is and implement `IDisposable` interface for your class (and `.Dispose()` your `DbContext` inside your class `Dispose` method). Of course, with the second option you need to `Dispose` your class wherever you create it.

Comment: There's few issues there, your `db` is public. Who owns the reference to it? should probably call `Dispose()` at some point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But it is still unclear if I have implement IDisposable.

It's a tricky question with a couple of answers:

- No, you should not.
- Yes, you should.
- No, you don't have to.

In general: 
`IDisposable` objects should be disposed at the end of their lifetime. There is some debate on whether the framework handles this for you, but that's a faulty approach. (at the bottom, under *The fauly approach*, I'll add why)

The responsibility of disposing lies, in general, at the creator. So; **if you create it, you dispose it**.

This is where @swdon's comment come's in;

> The biggest issue I see in his code is db is public. I don't know who is responsible for getting rid of correctly. – swdon Aug 2 '19 at 7:07

This is basically why you should not have public non-readonly IDisposable member fields. Because: you'll have no simple way of tracking it when the caller overwrites it and who's responsibe then to call `Dispose`?

---

### No, you should not

#### IoC

So, you might want to use an [IoC framework like Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity). What this IoC framework does is; it take over the responsibility of creating objects, and therefore, it's also responsible for the disposing of the objects. Do note: the purpose of an IoC framework is not about being a factory,  it's just one of the side effects.

So, with IoC, you won't *create* the member yourself, you request it. It might look something like this:

```
private GJobEntities _context;

//constructor: this object can also be created by the IoC framework.
public CacheManagementHelper (GJobEntities context)
{
    //set your field here
    _context = context;
}
```

If you use this, you don't have to implement `IDispossable` here because you are not creating the object yourself, you just request the context from the framework and let that call the `Dispose` method.

Why do I mention this? Because it's the default of [the future of .net](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/).

So, using this approach;

**No, you should not** implement IDisposable because you didn't create IDisposables, (but you should get rid of the DbContext creation).

---

### Yes, you should

#### IDisposable

If you need to stick to your current pattern - which makes sense - you should implement `IDisposable`. By creating IDispossable members, you are responsible for disposing them. You can delegate this to the creator of the class by implementing `IDisposable`.

```
public sealed class CacheManagementHelper : IDisposable
```

The creator of this object now creates the IDisposable object, and hence is responsible for disposing it.

Your only job is to implement the interface *correctly* and dispose your resources.

It's pretty though to implement it correctly from reading the docs. I would advise you to use this implementation: [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)

So, using this approach;

**Yes, you should** implement IDisposable and clean up your resources.

---

### No, you don't have to

#### Alternatively,

You could create the context while calling the function, keep it local and dispose it there. By this you'll overcome the need to implement `IDisposable`, because the creator of the context is also disposing it.

```
//keeping it local
public List<User> GetUsers()
{ 
    using (var db = new GJobEntities())
        return db.Users.ToList();
}
```

So, using this approach;

**No, you don't have to** implement IDisposable, because you are not creating IDisposable member fields.

---

#### The faulty approach

If you read "[Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)" you know that, if it's correctly implemented, you're pretty much safe guarded against memory leaks.

So, one might argue that you don't *need* to call `Dispose` all together because the garbage collector will do it for you.

This is a misconception.

The trouble with it is the following:

- 1) you don't know if the component you're calling is correctly implemented. It might leak if not being disposed (if using unmannaged memory).
- 2) memory leaks are; time related. Surprising hé? Look at it like this: the memory is back when you reboot the system or restart the application. It's not permanent. From the old days this was bound to the application lifetime span. But developments regarding to multi threading, serverless coding and so own, do require us to look at it slightly different. *The leak can be relvant within a specific time frame*. A good example of this is high memory consuming image processing or exhausting connection pools.

So, there is no way of telling when the garbage collector comes by and clean thing up. It might be not fast enough to create problems with: open connection counts, graphic resources etc. You're leaking, and rely on the garbage collector to fix your mess, which is a faulty approach.

---

*final remark:* a EF DbContext gather a lot of resources during it's life time by tracking all you changes (It's basically a unit of work). Keeping a long lived DbContext might cause a performance hit over time. So, just be aware of that.

Comment: Good, please add some examples then, Thank you!

Comment: The biggest issue I see in his code is `db` is public. I don't know who is responsible for getting rid of correctly.

Comment: @swdon Sorry It should be `private` but I still to have solution. Should it be `using (var db = new DBContext())` in each method or some `Dispose()`  ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide to consumers of your class possibility to dispose inner `db` context by implementing `IDisposable` interface:

```
public sealed class CacheManagementHelper : IDisposable 
{
   private readonly GJobEntities db = new GJobEntities();

   public List<User> GetUsers()
   { 
       return db.Users.ToList();
   }

   public void Dispose()
   { 
       db.Dispose();          
   }
}
```

Also you can implement `Finalizer` to ensure that resources will be released anyway even without any code changes on consumers side.