# How to dispose dbcontext in container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I create entity framework db context in startup

```
 services.AddTransient<MyContext>(_ => new MyContext(connectionString));
```

I inject this context in every service class where I need entity framework to add/edit/delete or what ever.

```
private readonly MyContext context;

public ArchiveService(MyContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

For IoC i am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.
This mean that my dependency injection container is responsible to dispose db context.

How can I be sure that context is disposed?

Do I need to configure something to dispose db context?

Thank you for help.

Comment: see this: [lifespan/scope of context in a winform application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663754/entity-framework-4-lifespan-scope-of-context-in-a-winform-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In asp.net core, all services which you registered with `AddTransient` are disposed together with a scope, so - when request ends. What's the difference between `Transient` and `Scoped` then you might ask? For `Transient` - new instance is created for every resolution. In your case - all your service classes will have distinct instances of `MyContext`. All of them will be disposed when request ends. For `Scoped` - only one instance will be created for given request (scope), so all your services would have shared the same instance, which is disposed when request ends.